# Удаление элемента массива из сессии в CodeIgniter

Tags: массивы, сессия, php, codeigniter

Привет всем. Пишу своё первое приложение на CodeIgniter.

У меня есть массив в сессии:

```
[after] => Array(

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_product] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_product] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id_product] => 3
        )
)
```

Вопрос в том - как мне удалить например:

```
[2] => Array

    (
        [id_product] => 2
    )
```

Пробую $this->session->unset_userdata("after"), Но удаляется вся сессия after. 
Подскажите как правильно это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter не знаю, но это не отдельный язык, так что можно и:

```
$tmp = $this->session->userdata('after');
unset($tmp[2]);
$this->session->set_userdata('after', $tmp);
```

Comment: Я написал следующим образом:

$after = $this->session->userdata('after');

foreach($after as $key => $item){
        if($item['id_product'] == $id_product){
 unset($after[$key]);
 break;
        }
}
   
 if(empty($after)){
 $this->session->unset_userdata('after');
 redirect($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
 }else{
 $this->session->set_userdata('after', $after);
 redirect($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
 }